# Javascript: Remove element from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and I want to delete some elements. My array is `arrayAuxiliar`. My code is the following one:

```
        for( var i = 0; i < arrayAuxiliar.length; i++)
        { 
            if (arrayAuxiliar[i] == valueFirts) {
                 arrayAuxiliar.splice(i,1);             
            }
            else if(arrayAuxiliar[i] == value){
                arrayAuxiliar.splice(i,1);  
            }
        }
```

Example of what is happening:

- Initial values: `arrayAuxiliar = [3,2,1], valueFirst = 1, value = 2`
- Final values: `arrayAuxiliar = [3,1]`

I know this happens because `splice()` changes the original array and that's for this reason the comparasion between `arrayAuxiliar[i] == valueFirts` is never true. I've also tried to use `remove arrayAuxiliar[i]` but it returns `[3,,]`.

How can I solve this situation in order to get the only element that does not verify the conditions which is `3`? The idea was the final result be `[3]` and I could get it by a `arrayAuxiliar[0]` command.

Comment: You could count down instead of counting up.

Comment: If you're not stuck on modifying the array in place you can use `Array.filter()` to get the elements that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `filter` would be more appropiate. You can try:

```js
let arrayAuxiliar = [3, 2, 1]
const valueFirst = 1
const value = 2

arrayAuxiliar = arrayAuxiliar.filter(i => i !== valueFirst && i !== value)

console.log(arrayAuxiliar)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter` and `includes` method

```js
const array = [3, 2, 1]
const remove_list = [2, 1]

const res = array.filter(num => !remove_list.includes(num))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const arr = [3,2,1];
const valueFirst = 1;
const value = 2;

console.log(arr.filter(item => ![value, valueFirst].includes(item)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use reduce function

```
function test(arrayAuxiliar, valueFirts, value) {
  return arrayAuxiliar.reduce((acc,rec) => {
    if ((rec === value) || (rec === valueFirts)) {
      return [...acc]
    }
    return [...acc, rec]
  }, [])
}
console.log(test([3,2,1,4,1,2,2,3,1,4,5,8,2,5], 1, 2))
```